# If text box value matches then make that specific label text to yes else no

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying check if the text of label matches with the text box if matches then make that specific label text to yes else no but in my code am not sure what is wrong but that is not happening for all it is showing "no" it self

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L6d39f10/4/)

HTML

```
<input class="master" value="1">

    <label class="user_label" >1</label>
            <label class="user_label" >0</label>
        <label class="user_label" >1</label>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
      var master = $('input.master').get(0).value; // get the master value
    var fn = function() {
        return this.text === master ? "yes" : "noo";//if current text-box matches master,then yes else no

    };
    $('label.user_label').text(fn); // loop and replace text for each user input


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.text` will be `undefined` inside `fn`, because `this` is a DOM node, and it doesn't have `text` property.

You can wrap it as a jQuery object and use the `text()` method:

```
var fn = function() {
    return $(this).text() === master ? "yes" : "noo";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6d39f10/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code as follows, second parameter in **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text)** callback function refers the old text value. You can use **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val)** for getting value in jQuery.

```js
var val = $('input.master').val();
$('.user_label').text(function(i, text){
  return val === text ? 'yes' : 'no';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="master" value="1">

<label class="user_label">1</label>
<label class="user_label">0</label>
<label class="user_label">1</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

when fn passed into $('label.user_label').text(fn) the context changed but still this.text is undefined. use this.textContent,this.innerHTML,$(this).text()

use text to compare and then modify it that makes logic odd， should it be like this?

```js
 $(function() {
   $('input.master').keyup(function() {
     var master = $(this).val(); // get the master value
     var fn = function() {
       return $(this).attr('data-val') === master ? "yes" : "noo"; //if current text-box matches master,then yes else no

     };
     $('label.user_label').text(fn); // loop and replace text for each user input


   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="master" value="">

<label class="user_label" data-val="1"></label>
<label class="user_label" data-val="0"></label>
<label class="user_label" data-val="1"></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var master = $('input.master').get(0).value; // get the master value

    $('label.user_label').each(function(){
      if($(this).text() === master){
        $(this).text("yes");
      }else{
        $(this).text("no");
      }
    });


});
```